# Количество входов в игру в течении недели

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Подскажите как можно реализовать задачу:

- если игрок в течении 7 дней заходил в игру, то ...

Код:

```
public void CountSpin()
{
    // attempts to do somethingpho
    if (PREFS_START_GAME.Day == DateTime.Today.Day) 
        Debug.Log ("Даты равны");

     else if (DateTime.Today.Day > PREFS_START_GAME.Day) { // Если заходил в игру
        PREFS_COUNT_START_GAME++; // Количество входов в неделю
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CountStartGame", PREFS_COUNT_START_GAME);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("StartGame7Day",    DateTime.Today.Day);
        GameManager.Instance.SetProfileCountStartGame (PREFS_COUNT_START_GAME); // прогресс в достижениях

    } else if ((DateTime.Today.Day - PREFS_START_GAME.Day) > 1) // Если игрок не заходил в игру
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CountStartGame", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("StartGame7Day",    DateTime.Today.Day);
    }


}
public DateTime loadFromPlayerPrefs() // хз как записать день даты в PlayerPrefs с GetInt
{
    return new DateTime(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("startGame7Day", PREFS_START_GAME.Day));
}
void Awake()
{   

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("StartGame7Day",    DateTime.Today.Day);
    loadFromPlayerPrefs ();
    Debug.Log ("loadFromPlayerPrefs " + loadFromPlayerPrefs().Day);
    PREFS_COUNT_START_GAME  = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CountStartGame");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В `PlayerPrefs` вписывать сколько подряд дней заходил и текущий день.

1. При запуске получаем из `PlayerPrefs` последний учтённый день и количество учтённых дней.

   1. Сравниваем с текущим днём. Если они равны, ничего не делаем.
   2. Если текущий день на 1 больше того, что получен из `PlayerPrefs`, то сохраняем в `PlayerPrefs` текущий день, наращиваем количество учтённых дней на 1 и тоже сохраняем.
   3. Если разница больше 1, значит игрок несколько дней не заходил. Сохраняем в `PlayerPrefs` текущий день, количество учтённых дней устанавливаем в 1 и тоже сохраняем.
2. Если после всех манипуляций количество учтённых дней стало 7, то...

Естественно при таком варианте нет защиты от тех, кто перематывает время на устройстве.

Comment: а к юнити xml файл привязать нельзя?

Comment: В таком варианте нет кое-чего посерьезнее - защиты, любой более-менее уверенный пользователь того же андроида легко найдет и поменяет данные, которые, скорее всего, прямо влияют на успешную монетизацию. Надо хотя бы шифровать данные.

Comment: @SeeSharp, можно, но это ничем не будет отличаться от PlayerPrefs

Comment: Всё спасибо за уточнения

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а разве на Android `PlayerPrefs` не в интернал памяти, к которой нет доступа без рута?

Comment: @Suvitruf именно так, но разве это настолько надежная защита? В любом случае считаю, что можно хоть какой-то базовый алгоритм для шифрования применить, понятное дело, что можно зареверсить, все это взломать, но даже такой подход оттолкнет большинство "хакеров" :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker зависит то того, какова критичность данных. Может их и вовсе защищать не стоит.

Comment: @Suvitruf справедливо

Comment: задача не требует особой защиты, это маленькое достижение, можете подсказать как сравнивать даты ? У меня не получается, в условие compareTo запихивал и просто PlayerPrefs.Day == DateTime.ToDay тоже ошибки. При запуске сохранять последний день или лучше при выходе? не будет такого что каждый день я буду заходить и каждый день будет записываться как последний ?

Comment: Вам нужно сохранять ровно 3 цифры - год, месяц и день, при должном старании это можно "зашить" в одну цифровую переменную. По вашим словам не совсем ясно, что вы делаете и в чем ошибка - правьте ваш вопрос и вставьте туда код, который у вас сейчас написан. Обновлять последний день лучше при входе, т.к. приложение может вылететь, телефон может зависнуть, все это не позволит сохранить эту переменную при выходе. Вам нужно сравнивать текущий день с сохраненным, если сохраненный день был раньше, чем текущий - отнимаете из текущий даты сохраненный день и получаете необходимое число дней.

Comment: не уверен что я всё правильно сделал, код выставил выше